# How can I convert the following flat records to a hierarchical structure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data

I have the following record in Table 1:

```
L1   L1DESC  L2   L2DESC  L3    L3DESC  L4     L4DESC  L5      L5DESC  L6         L6DESC
10   L1      101  L2      101A  L3      101A27 L4      101A27B L5      101A27B5   L6
```

There are six level of hierarchies, and in this scenario, L1 is a root, L2 is a child of L1, L3 is a child of L2, and so on.

Table 2 is a simple hierarchical schema

Level -- Description -- Parent

which means I'd want to convert that single record to the following hierarchical records:

```
LEVEL         DESCRIPTION    PARENT
10            L1             NULL
101           L2             L1
101A          L3             L2
101A27        L4             L3
101A27B       L5             L4
101A27B5      L6             L5
```

What would be the fastest/most elegant way to do it in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: How does the XML describe which levels are parents of each other? I it looks more like an array to me.

Comment: each record represents a full hierarchy. It's a given that L2 will be a children of L1 and so on, @AdamSchiavone

Comment: How are you looking to accomplish this? I would recommend writing a quick and dirty utility in C#/VB to read in the file and send it to the database. I have never read files with SQL only....

Comment: The question title says "In SQL server", and I tagged the question t-sql :) I was doing it in C# but I'm working with up to 100k records, so individual updates are not an option, @AdamSchiavone

Comment: One quick google search later and I learn that you can in fact read a file with SQL.... I think I wont be of much help on this one if you want to use SQL alone. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah. What you were asking didn't totally click until I read it again. I think I need some sleep.

Comment: Actually the question was not that clear Adam. I didnt even need to mention the XML thing, since I already have inserted the data in SQL. The only problem is I received it in a flat representation and I want to change that to Hierarchical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a fixed hierarchy, simply union the results.

```
SELECT  L1
       ,L1DESC
       ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Parent
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  L2
       ,L2DESC
       ,L1Desc
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  L3
       ,L3DESC
       ,L2Desc
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  L4
       ,L4DESC
       ,L3Desc
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  L5
       ,L5DESC
       ,L4Desc
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  L6
       ,L6DESC
       ,L5Desc
FROM    T1
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32e33/2

Comment: hah, I hadn't checked SO today and came up with pretty much the same. Apparently I just needed some sleep. Thanks @souplex